# Creating new table-row with colspan changes cell sizes in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm working on a rather complex problem, and have tried to reduce my problem into a short code example.

When I create a new `<tr>` in a table with jQuery, and set colspan to total-number-of-columns, the widths (which are not set in the code) of the table cells change. This happens in IE9 but not in Chrome. I understand that I can give the cell sizes explicitly in the code, but I can't really do that in the solution I work with.

Here's the code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var expanded = false;
    var $detailsRow;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //toggle the details row
        $(".selectable-row").click(function(){
            if(expanded){
                $detailsRow.remove();
                expanded = false;
            }else{
                $detailsRow = $("<tr class=\"child-row\"><td colspan=\"4\">");
                $detailsRow.find("td").text("Hellohellohellohellohellohello Hellohellohellohellohellohello Hellohellohellohellohellohello Hellohellohellohellohellohello Hellohellohellohellohellohello Hellohellohellohellohellohello Hellohellohellohellohellohello Hellohellohellohellohellohello Hellohellohellohellohellohello");
                $detailsRow.insertAfter($(this));
                expanded = true;
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div style="width:1000px">
    <table border="1" style="width:100%">
        <tr class="selectable-row">
            <td>2012-09-03 11:33</td>
            <td>This is the 2nd column</td>
            <td>The 3rd column</td>
            <td>The last one</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

[image: Note that it's a subtle difference, the second one is expanded, and the date-cell is slightly smaller]
Note that it's a subtle difference, the second one is expanded, and the date-cell is slightly smaller.

Can someone explain why this is happening, and if there is a fix? Maybe wrapping the inside of the cell with a div somehow. I have tried it all I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is a [pixel-rounding error](http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/).
[Here](http://agilewebmasters.com/robert/percentage-rounding-and-sub-pixel-perfection/) another link talking about it.

If you take your code and post it into js fiddle, you will get the error you talked about for div width of 1000, but not 1001, nor 1002, but again for 1003, 1004, and not again for 1005...
If you change the column number to 3, Chrome will also show you the error for 1001, 1002.

I'm not sure how the table column widths get recalculated when you add the col-span , which cause the shift in the first place, since the table's dimensions itself don't change.

And as K.K. mentioned, setting width: 25% also fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue for my test-example... but not for my real-world example ;) I learnt about pixel-rounding though!

Comment: Checking in js fiddle, I can fix the rounding issue in Chrome with a width of 1001, but in IE9 it stays the same? http://jsfiddle.net/JYpwD/

Answer (score 0):

did you applied any css for control the cells width?, because after adding a css property on cells, it's stop smaller / larger.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .selectable-row td { width: 25%; }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I wrote, I can't set the cell sizes explicitly in the code in the solution I work with.